# CUDA calling function in different program

Tags: cuda, glsl

In cuda, is it possible to call a **device** function that is defined in a different program?

I would like to have a program containing multiples **device** functions and then, create different kernels (that could be compiled in different cubin), but be able to call these functions.

So, what I want is:

- A cubin that would have utility functions A, B, and C
- A cubin that would be able to call functions A and B
- A cubin that would be able to call function A and C

Is there a way to do that?

And a similar question, is it possible to have a sort of function pointer similar to the subroutine in GLSL in CUDA?

Comment: If you are trying to ask whether CUDA supports device code libraries, the answer is yes

Comment: Do I have to do anything special? Or just load the modules in a proper order?

Comment: In [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526645/how-to-create-a-static-lib-using-cuda-5-0-6-5-and-vs2010-problem-solved-and-bug-found-/) in the NVIDIA developer forums I presented a minimal worked example of how to create and use a device code library, for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Do you have an example with cubins? In your example, the project is linked together. But I would like to have individual cubin files. Then they could be loaded dynamically, a bit like plugins or DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using cubins.

In CUDA, it is impossible to compile to a cubin file with unsatisfied dependencies. All CUDA code *must* be available to the assembler/linker at compile time, be they in object files or libraries. If you don't do this, the cubin assembly stage will fail in unsatisfied dependencies. Therefore, what you propose can't work. The way device function pointers work in CUDA also precludes the possibility of using runtime pointer assignment to pass previously anonymous functions to a kernel. This is because there is no way to get device function handles at runtime from a cubin using the host APIs. To do that requires device code, and device code can't work for the reasons outlined above.

You have two choices here:

1. Use separate compilation and libraries to build your utility functions into a service library, and then build the cubin against that library using the device linker
2. Use JIT PTX compilation and assembly at runtime. If you have all the code you need compiled to PTX, you could devise a system to concatenate all of the required PTX code into a single input to a JIT compilation call from the driver API. That should circumvent the need to resolve everything at compilation time

Finally, yes, you can have function pointers in CUDA, but as discussed above, they won't help you here.